# Is it normal that web application URL is always of app server rather than WFE?

Tags: 2013, web-application, url

I have 1 App server and 2 WFEs. Web Application service is stopped on App server while it is started on WFEs.

I created a new web application and I noticed the URL is of App server for e.g. `http://appserver`

I thought since I have stopped web application service so URL will be something like `http://wfe01` or `http://wfe02` but looks like that's not the case.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the Web Application you decide what should be the URL of it. And in your setup it should not be the URL of any of your servers, but the URL for the load balancer which distributes the work between wfe01 and wfe02.

And normally you'll leave the web application service running on the App server as well and let Search Crawl use that locally by having the hosts file on the App server point the load balanced URL to itself.

Comment: But when I created web application, it didn't give me any option to chose URL specially that of load balancer. How do I do that?

Comment: When you create your web app you have the option of specifying Host Header (and port number) that's the building blocks for the URL

Comment: Ok I see now there is Host Header option. But I was also able to change URL by going to Alternate Mapping Access and then changing http://appserver to http://wfe01 and then adding another Internal URL as http://wfe02. Did I do it right?

Comment: No it should not be wfe01 or wfe02 but the Load balancing URL. Take a look at [Prepare SharePoint Farm – Part 3 Prepare NLB for SharePoint Web Front End WFE Servers](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2012/05/29/prepare-sharepoint-farm-part-3-prepare-nlb-for-sharepoint-web-front-end-wfe-servers.aspx) and the next part of that series even though that's for SP2010